# Python Script only works when run from directory

Tags: python

I have a script that works (kind of) but only if ran when you are currently in the directory path

```
directoryChosen = sys.argv[1]




for f in os.listdir(directoryChosen):
    fname, fext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if not f.startswith('.'):
        print f

        print fname + " Is fname"
        dest_path = fname
        print dest_path + " is dest path"
        print fname + "this is fname"
        if os.path.isdir(fname):
            print "Ended here/ Start work here"
            shutil.copy2(directoryChosen + '/' + f, dest_path)
        if not os.path.isdir(fname):
            print "working here kind of..lets make directories"

            os.mkdir(dest_path)
            print " Path is created"

            shutil.copy2(directoryChosen + f, dest_path)
```

**Works**
If I run

```
 python /Users/eeamesX/PycharmProjects/Workmain/groupFiles.py continuous/

2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd.csv
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd Is fname
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd is dest path
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6ddthis is fname
working here kind of..lets make directories
 Path is created
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd.wav
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd Is fname
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd is dest path
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6ddthis is fname
Ended here/ Start work here
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd.xml
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd Is fname
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd is dest path
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6ddthis is fname
Ended here/ Start work here
```

**doesnt work**

python groupFiles.py /Users/eeamesX/work/data/GERMANY/DE_026/continuous/

```
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd.csv
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd Is fname
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd is dest path
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6ddthis is fname
Ended here/ Start work here
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd.wav
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd Is fname
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd is dest path
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6ddthis is fname
Ended here/ Start work here
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd.xml
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd Is fname
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6dd is dest path
2015-06-01#e3cea6c4-07f2-4b84-985d-5ecabae9a6ddthis is fname
Ended here/ Start work here
 grouped the files boss
```

I want it to create the directory if it is run both ways!  Any help?

Comment: Can you write a new script with just two or three lines which also exhibits the same problem? See [**`mcve`**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names returned by `os.listdir` don't include the directory prefix. So every function that takes a filename requires you to concatenate the directory with the name. E.g.

```
    if os.path.isdir(directoryChosen + '/' + fname):
        print "Ended here/ Start work here"
        shutil.copy2(directoryChosen + '/' + f, directoryChosen + '/' + dest_path)
```